# Java: Regex to identify punctuations in a sentence and delete them

Tags: java, regex

I have the following string:

```
String input = "Remove from em?ty sentence 1? Remove from sentence 2! But not from ip address 190.168.10.110!";
```

I want to remove punctuation marks at the right places. My output needs to be:

```
String str = "Remove from em?ty sentence 1 Remove from sentence 2 But not from ip address 190.168.10.110";
```

I am using the following code:

```
while (stream.hasNext()) { 
    token = stream.next();
    char[] tokenArray = token.toCharArray();
    token = token.trim();

    if(token.matches(".*?[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}[\\.\\?!]+")){
        System.out.println("case2");
        stream.previous();
        int len = token.length()-1;
        for(int i = token.length()-1; i>7; i--){
            if(tokenArray[i]=='.'||tokenArray[i]=='?'||tokenArray[i]=='!'){
                --len;
            }
            else
                break;
        }
        stream.set(token.substring(0, len+1));
    }
    else if(token.matches(".*?\\b[a-zA-Z_0-9]+\\b[\\.\\?!]+")){
        System.out.println("case1");
        stream.previous();
        str = token.replaceAll("[\\.\\?!]+", "");
        stream.set(str);

        System.out.println(stream.next());                          
    }
}
```

'Tokens' are getting sent from the 'input' string. Can you please indicate what i am doing wrong in terms of regex or the logic?

A punctuation is considered one when it ends a sentence, is not present within an ip address, not within words such as `!true`, `emp?ty` (leave them alone). Also may be followed by a space or end of string.

Comment: Because a token might contain an ip address or a word such as `!true`, where both are legit uses of `!` and `.`

Comment: What you have done wrong is that you haven't taken the time to figure out exactly what you want to remove and what you want to be left intact. After you have done that, we can try to help you correcting the regex.

Comment: @Keppil Isn't it clear that punctuations need to be removed but not when present in ip addresses or within words?

Comment: You added more conditions in your comments to Casimirs answer below (some punctuations should be kept untouched). Please specify exactly what you mean by punctuations, and when they should be removed or not.

Comment: @Keppil Does it make it clear?

Comment: Not really. `May be followed by space or end of String`? So how should the following `String` be treated: `Hi!How are you?`?

Comment: Output: `Hi How are you`

Comment: Ok. How would you expect the regex to know the difference between that one and `He?lo how are you?`? Like I said, you need to think through all the possible cases you can encounter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern:

```
\\p{Punct}(?=\\s|$)
```

and replace it with nothing.

example:

```
String subject = "Remove from em?ty sentence 1? Remove from sentence 2! But not from ip address 190.168.10.110!";
String regex = "\\p{Punct}(?=\\s|$)";
String result = subject.replaceAll(regex, "");
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: tried your pattern. It is not working:
    while(m1.find()){
               token=token.replaceAll(regex1, "");
      }

Comment: @user2823318: In what cases?

Comment: In the test string given in the question.

Comment: @user2823318: There's probably an error in your code, I write an example of use, try it.

Comment: Take for example `String subject = "'em?ty'";`
Output should be `'em?ty'`. Output using your pattern: `'em?ty`

Comment: @user2823318: In this case replace the `\\p{Punct}` character class by a character class with the punctuation characters you want to remove.

Answer (score 0):

```
String input = "Remove from em?ty sentence 1? Remove from sentence 2! But not from ip address 190.168.10.110!";
System.out.println(input.replaceAll("[?!]", ""));
```

Gave output:

```
Remove from emty sentence 1 Remove from sentence 2 But not from ip address 190.168.10.110
```

Comment: its remove ? from em?ty.

Comment: do not need to remove `?` from `em?ty`. And punctuation could include `.` too. so what you have suggested will not work with ip address

Answer (score 0):

Why not use

```
string.replaceAll("[?!] ", ""));
```

Comment: Won't satisfy my output.

Comment: what does it give you and what are you expecting ?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it the other way around.

```
if(token.matches("[\\.\\!\\:\\?\\;] "){
token.replace("");
}
```

Now, I am assuming that the punctuation marks would have a trailing space. It leaves out only the last punctuation, mark in the sentence, which you can remove separately.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work. It rules out everything, then takes what punctuation is
significant to you. `[,.!?]`

Just replace with $1

```
    # ([^\pL\pN\s]*[\pL\pN](?:[\pL\pN_-]|\pP(?=[\pL\pN\pP_-]))*)|[,.!?]
    # "([^\\pL\\pN\\s]*[\\pL\\pN](?:[\\pL\\pN_-]|\\pP(?=[\\pL\\pN\\pP_-]))*)|[,.!?]"

    (                              # (1 start)
         [^\pL\pN\s]* [\pL\pN] 
         (?:
              [\pL\pN_-] 
           |  \pP 
              (?= [\pL\pN\pP_-] )
         )*
    )                              # (1 end)
 |  
    [,.!?]
```